# How to hide or disable navigation bottom tablet?

Tags: android

I want to hide or disable navigation bottom tablet in android. I have search and use

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

But when focus `EditText` then keyboard appear and navigation also appear. Can you help me when keyboard appear navigation hide or help me disable button in navigation. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Post your xml layout

Comment: for me reason why no hide navigation when focus edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the navigation bar using the SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION flag. This snippet hides both the navigation bar and the status bar:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

source: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation)